# Recording Sorting Macros in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, rows

I've been tasked to

Record a Macros for Repetitive Tasks (Sorting
values in a row)
I need to record a macro that will sort each ROW of a set of data I can only get it to do a few rows I need it to do 50+ rows

set, sort values based on row-based ranges and
incorporate the use of a Button

I know how to create a button but he wants one button to work for all rows.

Comment: A little difficult to suggest approaches with no idea how your data is laid out, or what your recorded macro looks like.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim rw As Range, ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet  'where the data is
    
    For Each rw In ws.Range("A3:J44").Rows 'work on each row individually
        With ws.Sort                       'following code adapted from the macro recorder output...
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add2 Key:=rw, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, _
                   Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange rw
            .Header = xlGuess
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlLeftToRight '<<< key part
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With
    Next rw
End Sub
```